# Bootstrap class="btn btn-primary noty" won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

been starting to learn bootstrap, etc. And can't figure out, how to get trought this bug...

I got simple input form(For example username,password,button)

And I want my button show notifiction after it has submited the form.

Like this:
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary noty" data-noty-options='{"text":"Part sucessfully edited","layout":"topRight","type":"success"}'>Edit</button>`

But.. When I press the button, it only shows notifiction, but dosn't submit the form.

If I choose class `btn btn-primary` not `btn btn-primary noty` it submits form, but dosn't show notifiction

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-noty-options='{"text":"Part sucessfully edited","layout":"topRight","type":"success"}'>Edit</button>`

[image]

Comment: You can create the div with that class, and with Jquery you can do something like `$('.btn btn-primary noty').show()` i think this might work

Comment: Your button tag should be within the form tag in order to submit form successfully.

Comment: @Niraj It is located inside the form. But it won't submit when it displays notifiction

Comment: @crelix20 Tried to reproduce on Codepen. Check if i am on right path.
Its working here.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrNRmW